# Exporting multiple fields (sender's email address, etc) from Lotus Notes to Excel

Tags: lotus-notes, export-to-excel, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

My work requires me to keep a register on incoming emails in an excel.  Is there a way which I can generate / export to an excel showing (i) sender's email address, (ii) date and time of receipt, (iii) time of my reply / forward and (iv) the recipient's email address, for all my emails in my inbox?

Now I just copy from Lotus Notes and paste to Excel one by one which was so tedious.  If it is not possible to have all the above four information be extracted / exported to excel, just extract as much as possible, and I will do the remaining by copy and paste.  Thanks a lot in advance!

(I am using Lotus Notes 9.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to build a view with the relevant data, mark the documents, and use Edit -> Copy As -> Table from the Notes menu. Then just paste data to Excel.

Comment: This is a great method which had solved my problem! Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Can you accept the answer so others will know it's the right solution?

Comment: I have actually clicked the up arrow but it didnt show up because I'm a new user, but there is a tick... I thought it means I have successfully voted.  Now I click the tick which I suppose it means a correct solution.  Let me know if it's not. =)